# HTTP 401 for osfruntime_strings.js while loading add-in

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I'm facing `HTTP 401` for `osfruntime_strings.js` while loading my OWA add-in on IE and Edge browser. This is working fine on Firefox and Chrome browser.

[image]

If I try to load the url on IE/Edge browser in a separate tab then there's no issue, I get `HTTP 200`.

As this is the first web request made when I try to load my add-in and it fails, my add-in UI doesn't load There is no web request made to load the add-in html page and other subsequent web requests.

Is this something that needs to be fixed on the add-in side or on the Exchange server side.

Comment: May want to examine the full trace for authentication (might be easier to use Fiddler instead of built-in debugger but either one should be fine) -- how does the original user authenticate (Kerberos, NTLM, Basic, Forms), and what does this 401 response say -- what type of authentication is it looking for?  Then compare it to a working trace.  There must be some clues there!

Comment: @Sagar, can you try a random add-in from the Store to see if this issue repro's?

Comment: @BrianClink In the 401 Unauthorized response I see `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, NTLM, Basic realm=mail.mycompany.com` and `Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0`

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Other add-ins do load, this is what the end user is saying. unfortunately I cannot take remote access and debug.

Comment: Now compare the login, and the request for osfruntime_strings.js in both the working and non-working traces. There should be some clues there.  osfruntime_strings.js is just a static file, so IIS is the one serving the file.  In our environment this file is being served from the back-end, based on the response headers (e.g. X-CalculatedBETarget: server.root; X-BackEnd-Begin: 2018-12-05T10:24:01.982; X-BackEnd-End: 2018-12-05T10:24:02.013).  Beyond this, it is a bit out of my capability to t-shoot on a discussion thread.

Comment: If other add-ins are working fine in IE and Edge browser, can you try out the instructions from @BrianClink to troubleshoot your setup and share any findings?

Comment: For some additional info, is this in Exchange On-Premise, or Office 365? What version for each?